# Discrete Mathematics Dealing with Equivalence Classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be a finite set with $n\geq 4$ elements
and let $\rho$ be an equivalence relation on $A$.
Suppose that there are exactly 4 equivalence
classes, $C_1,C_2, C_3,C_4$.
Moreover we know that $\lvert C_1\rvert=\lvert C_2\rvert=1$.
Let $a\in A$ be an element that we know is in $C_3$.

What is the *maximum* number of ordered pairs of $(x,y)\in\rho$
in which $a$ can occur (meaning $a=x$ or $a=y$ or $a=x=y$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $C_3, C_4$ are not empty, consider the set $A=\lbrace 1,2,3,4k:k=1,...,n-3\rbrace$ and the usual equivalence relation defined by the congruence modulo $4$ i.e. $(x,y)\in \rho \Leftrightarrow x-y=4z, z\in \mathbb{Z}$.

It is easy to see that $C_1=\lbrace 1\rbrace, C_2=\lbrace 2 \rbrace, C_4=\lbrace 3 \rbrace, C_3=\lbrace 4k:k=1,...,n-3\rbrace$ and that there can't be a class with more elements than $C_3$ (otherwise, $C_4=\emptyset$) and the  *maximum* number of ordered pairs of $(x,a),(a,x)\in\rho$ is the number of pairs of the form $(x,a),(a,x),x\in C_3$. Since $|C_3|=n-3$, there are $2(n-3)-1$ pairs (two for each $x\in C_3: (x,a),(a,x)$ and $-1$ because we counted $(a,a)$ twice).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  If $(a,y)\in\rho$, can you determine which of the four equivalence classes contains $y$?

Comment: wouldn't it have to be $C_3$ ?

Comment: Yes, so what is the maximum number of options you have for $y$?  See if you can finish the problem from here.

Comment: It would be n-1

Comment: How do you get $n-1$ elements in $C_3$?

Comment: OK, so put this together with the comment at the end of your question ("meaning. . .") and I think you will be able to complete the solution.  Good luck!